# Thread Management Object

Tags: .net, events, multithreading, dispatcher

I feel rather foolish as this is just a short question.

I was reading about a bunch of thread management helper classes in .net, specifically one that aids the storage of threads to help a service manager object automatically invoke delegates onto the subscribing thread. I'm pretty sure it had something to do with creating dispatchers.

Totally forgotten the name, can't find it :( Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for either the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) or [`AsyncOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.aspx) classes.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. Thank you very much.